# Dotnetnuke migration from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, dotnetnuke, database-migration

I'm trying to upgrade my DNN v6 from a SQL Server 2005 to a SQL Server 2012. My problem is, after modifying the web.config to match the new appSettings, my website automaticaly runs the install wizard. My IIS was running on a 2003 server and is now on a 2012 server.

Is it a necessary step to install a new instance of DNN?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution. I restored my original version of database and finaly I passed every first and last upgrade of every major version. It worked well then.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.  It is necessary that you move your database to the new SQL Server.  Did you do that?

If so, it is likely that there is a login/permission issue with the moved database.  Can you connect to it via SQL Server Management Studio using the exact same credentials as in your connection string?